# How to implement gmail-like hotkeys

Tags: javascript, hotkeys

I'd like to implement keyboard hotkeys in a web application. So far I've been using the [jquery.hotkeys plugin](https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys), and it allowed me to implement simple hotkeys (e.g. single keystrokes like <kbd>a</kbd>).

Now to support some more complex navigation via the keyboard, I'd like to implement 'multi-key' hotkeys like in gmail, where for example pressing <kbd>g</kbd> (for 'go') followed by <kbd>i</kbd> (for 'inbox') takes you the the inbox.

Does anyone know of a javascript component (jquery plugin or similar) for that task? Or what would be a good approach to implement such hotkeys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a better solution to this using [keymaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster) with the [keymaster-sequence](https://github.com/chevalric/keymaster-sequence) plugin.

The sources are here [`keymaster.js`](https://raw.github.com/madrobby/keymaster/master/keymaster.js) and here [`keymaster.sequence.js`](https://raw.github.com/chevalric/keymaster-sequence/master/keymaster.sequence.js)

Use them like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/madrobby/keymaster/master/keymaster.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/chevalric/keymaster-sequence/master/keymaster.sequence.min.js"></script>
<script>
key.sequence(["g","i"], function () {
  var el = document.getElementById("result");
  el.innerHTML = "You first pressed 'g', then you pressed 'i'";
});

</script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Here's a small demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/Nwdyd/1/ which also shows collision handling (binding `g` as well as `g i`)

Comment: Running the sample as is src links from raw.github.com no longer working for me; but the linked github projects work with local code.

Comment: The links resolve ok - However, they're only included for demonstration purposes and should **NOT** be used as a CDN.

Comment: Maybe I screwed it up, but I'd copy/pasted that exactly into my app and it didn't work, when I copied the contents to local files it worked great.

Comment: doesn't work when there is another element (in the page) focused. Check [http://jsfiddle.net/EyNek/](http://jsfiddle.net/EyNek/) out

Answer (score 5):

Set a global boolean value when <kbd>g</kbd> is pressed. Then check if it's set when <kbd>i</kbd> is pressed.
You can optionally implement a timeout on the <kbd>g</kbd> press so that you have limited time to press <kbd>i</kbd> afterwards.

```
var goPressed = false;
function hotkeyPressed (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == KEYCODE_FOR_G) {
        goPressed == true;
        //Optionally:
        setTimeout(clearPresses, 3000);
    }
    if (event.keyCode == KEYCODE_FOR_I && goPressed) {
        gotoInbox();
    }
}

function clearPresses() {
    goPressed = false;
}
```

Comment: It's not that easy. The two keys must be pressed within some define time, to form a valid hotkey.

Comment: That's what my clearPresses function is for... If you don't press i within 3000 milliseconds, the boolean is set back to false.

Comment: 3 seconds is a VERY long time in key press land.

Comment: @Slomojo Not sure it is for a sequence of keys, regardless it's clearly configurable / up to the implementer...

Comment: I only mentioned it because both your and Spoike's answer duplicate the 3000ms (since he's working from your code) - and as such, tentatively speaking, it's a suggestion of a sensible default. Of course it is configurable, however I thought it was worth pointing out to future readers that 3 seconds is a pretty long time when pressing keys or buttons. - Ultimately, dear reader, do some UX tests and tune it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You could still use the plugin by adding a state and a timeout, much as [Matt Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416083/3713) suggests.

```
var gWasPressed = false;    

var clearKeyState = function() {
    gWasPressed = false;
}

var changeKeyState = function() {
  gWasPressed = true;
  setTimeout(clearKeyState, 3000);
}

$(document).bind('keydown', 'g', changeKeyState);
$(document).bind('keydown', 'i', commandI);

var commandI = function() {
  if (gWasPressed) {
    // go to inbox
    clearKeyState();
  } else {
    // do whatever i was supposed to do if g wasn't pressed
  }
}
```

Alternate solution would be to rebind the keys when <kbd>g</kbd> is pressed, and unbind them when the timeout expires or when the secondary key <kbd>i</kbd> is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of hotKeys.js that works with 1.10+ version of jQuery. It is small, 100 line javascript file. 4kb or just 2kb minified. Here are some Simple usage examples are :

```
$('#myBody').hotKey({ key: 'c', modifier: 'alt' }, doSomething);

$('#myBody').hotKey({ key: 'f4' }, doSomethingElse);

$('#myBody').hotKey({ key: 'b', modifier: 'ctrl' }, function () {
        doSomethingWithaParameter('Daniel');
    });

$('#myBody').hotKey({ key: 'd', modifier :'shift' }, doSomethingCool);
```

Clone the repo from github : https://github.com/realdanielbyrne/HoyKeys.git or go to the github repo page https://github.com/realdanielbyrne/HoyKeys or fork and contribute.